# Android ListFragment displaying only last item repeated

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I'm trying to make a listfragment to display twenty items. As it stands only the last item in the list is displayed for all twenty items in the list. I've been looking at examples of listfragments and I can't tell what is wrong.

This is from the CourseFragment class that extends ListFragment:

```
private List<Course> mCourses;

public CourseFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mCourses = Schedule.get(getActivity()).getSchedule();
    CourseArrayAdapter<Course> mAdapter = new CourseArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mCourses);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
        Log.d("DEBUGTAG", "Course: " + mCourses.get(i));
    }

}
```

This is from the CourseArrayAdapter:

```
public CourseArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "getView " + position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View mLayout;
    if (convertView == null) {
        mLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_course, parent, false);
    } else {
        mLayout = convertView;
    }
    T mCourse = getItem(position);
    TextView mCourseTextView = (TextView) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.course_textview);
    mCourseTextView.setText(mCourse.toString());

    return mLayout;
}
```

And the onCreate of the MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager mFragManager = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment mFragment = mFragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_activity_framelayout);
    if(mFragment == null) {
        mFragment = new CourseFragment();
        mFragManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_activity_framelayout, mFragment).commit();
    }

}
```

Here is the instance variables and constructor of the Course class:

```
private static String sCourseName;
private static int sCourseNum;
private static String sInstructor;
private static String sDescription;

public Course(String mCourseName, int mCourseNum, String mInstructor, String mDescription) {
    sCourseName = mCourseName;
    sCourseNum = mCourseNum;
    sInstructor = mInstructor;
    sDescription = mDescription;
}
```

If any other code is needed to solve this, please let me know. Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Can you show constructor of courseArrayAdapter

Comment: Did you get same value for mCourse.tostring can you please tell me what is it printing

Comment: Updated to include that

Comment: @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getCourseNum() + " " + getCourseName() + " " + "\nInstructor: " + getInstructor();
    }

Comment: The for loop doesn't actually do anything, it is just for debugging. I moved setListAdapter to after it and it didn't change the output.

Comment: Create a list of courses in courseArrayAdapter and initialise it to objects which you are using in constructor and object of list to directly get the value at that position

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are suggesting. Could you please explain further or provide an example? Thanks

Comment: Ok i ll write in few minutes can you tell what value is getting set in list view

Comment: Currently, the listview is setting the toString value of the course. It is supposed to do this for every course but repeats the last entry instead.

Comment: where is your `View.setTag` and `View.getTag`?

Comment: @mark.jon
I don't think I ever do that. Where should they be?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this now mCourses will have data .i think it will not be repeated

```
private List<Course> mCourses;
public CourseArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects) {
super(context, resource, objects);
mCourses=objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
Log.d("DEBUG", "getView " + position);
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
View mLayout;
if (convertView == null) {
    mLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_course, parent, false);
} else {
    mLayout = convertView;
}
  // T mCourse = getItem(position);
TextView mCourseTextView = (TextView) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.course_textview);
mCourseTextView.setText(mCourses.get(position).toString());

return mLayout;
}
```

Comment: I had to change  the first line of code to:
    `private List<T> mCourses;`

It still is doing what it did before

Comment: Log.d("DEBUGTAG", "Course: " + mCourses.get(i)); are you getting different value every time here?

Comment: No, I am getting the same value repeated there too. It is the value of the toString method of the last item.

Comment: What is log in getview printing

Comment: Thanks for the help, it turns out the issue was elsewhere in the code. The issues were in the Course class. The instance variables were static.

Comment: Great...Happy coding